# (1.9) Get ID's of all a product's categories (on product page)

Tags: magento

So this week I managed to break my site by attempting to get the ID of the current category within the product page (catalog/product/view.phtml), using the following code

```
$category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

This actually works fine if you navigate into the product through the generic navigation, but when reaching a product from the front page 'featured products' link, everything falls over - presumably because I'm asking for a category ID when i'm not in a category.

What i'd like to know is how i can fetch an array of IDs of all the categories to which the current product belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento default catalog/product model has default method to get all category ids of a product.
Just try with

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//This will get the info of current product.

$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); 

$prodID = $product->getId();

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);

$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

foreach($categoryIds as $categoryIds1) {    
   $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds1);

//get all category ID in the current product.

   echo $category_name = $_category->getId();

//get all the Category Name of the Product.

   echo $category_name = $_category->getName();
}
```